# .htaccess redirection for two parts

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site with login which is in two parts - folders:
http://www.example.com/site-1
and http://example.com/site-2

if you come to http://www.example.com, you are redirected from index.php to http://example.com/site-2.

In each folder there are .htaccess files managin redirection.
For each folder I have declaration like this:

```
http://www.example.com/site-1:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site-2/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/site-1/$1 [R=301,L]

http://example.com/site-2:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site-2/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/site-2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

all is working good in http://example.com/site-2. But if I go to http://example.com/site-1, for visiting each page I have to login over and over again.

I think here is something wrong with .htaccess.
Your help would be really great. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to redirect from **`/site-1/`** to **`/site-1`**?

Comment: sorry typo .. I modified